# Amazon EC2 allow outbound access to AWS SDK endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-security-group

I have an Apache server running on an EC2 instance, from which I am serving a PHP webpage that lists EC2 instances under my account, allows for toggling them on/off, etc.

The problem is that the AWS SDK call (specifically `describeInstances`, but in general) can't reach the endpoint. I have looked into what IP ranges AWS uses, [described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html). I would like to avoid putting *all* of those IP ranges into my security group if possible. Because the endpoint resolves to different IPs in different requests, there doesn't seem to be one IP range that will work (besides `0.0.0.0/0`, which I don't want to use).

Is there a way to allow outbound access to specifically AWS-provided services without manually entering all of these IP ranges? It seems like there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: EC2 VPC endpoint is what you are looking for. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/interface-vpc-endpoints.html

Comment: why do you have to put IP address as security group? Couldn't you add your existing security group from other EC2 instances as inbound rule?

Comment: @jellycsc I added an internal endpoint, which allows the commands to work through the CLI, but not the SDK through PHP. I am still running into the same issue when running the command through the SDK.

Comment: @programing_is_hard No, because I am not trying to directly access other EC2 instances; I am trying to use the AWS SDK, which speaks to AWS, not directly to my instances.

Comment: Im still trying to understand what you are end goal is. So you are trying to get your php server to be able to turn on/off the other EC2 instances under your account through php SDK. In order for you to do it, you are saying you need your security group of your php server to be able to allow ip address of other ec2 instances. But you don't want to allow all address. Is that correct?